# Python to output value based from input text which is added into arrays

Tags: python, arrays, arraylist

I am a beginner when it comes to python coding but I am looking to find an output based from a few factors. I will try my best to explain.

There is 6 zones `ZONE = ["RED", "GREEN", "BLUE", "YELLOW", "PINK", "WHITE"]`

For argument sake there is two devices at the moment but there will be more, the devices are called **PIR** and **SMOKE**

When a new device comes online, I was python to assign it a new ZONE colour but if the ZONE already contains the same type of device, it should pick another ZONE unless if all the ZONEs already have the same device then it can start to double up and so forth.

When each device comes online, I collect the device details such as the MAC address and Device Type... the index of the array is one device

```
MAC = ["ABC","DEF","GHI"]
TYPE = ["PIR","PIR","SMOKE"]
ZONE = ["RED","GREEN","RED"]
```

When device number 4 comes online, I want python to tell me what would be the next available ZONE colour. As I've already got two PIR's in ZONE RED and GREEN, I would expect the next result for a PIR device to be **BLUE** and the next SMOKE device to be **GREEN**. Python would then send the ZONE colour to the new device so the device can set its zone colour mode (communication on that front is already working).

I have partly been able to get a test project working but it just shows me which colour would be next available but not taking the device type into account as well. My example is as follows:

```
ZONE = ["RED", "GREEN", "BLUE", "YELLOW", "PINK", "WHITE"]
ZONEDevices  = [0,0,0,0,0,0]
DEVICES = ["PIR", "PIR", "SMOKE"]
MAC = ["123", "456", "789"]
DEVICEZONE = ["RED", "GREEN", "RED"]

# Following counts how many devices are in each zone and adds to the array
ZONEDevices[0] = DEVICEZONE.count("RED")
ZONEDevices[1] = DEVICEZONE.count("GREEN")
ZONEDevices[2] = DEVICEZONE.count("BLUE")
ZONEDevices[3] = DEVICEZONE.count("YELLOW")
ZONEDevices[4] = DEVICEZONE.count("PURPLE")
ZONEDevices[5] = DEVICEZONE.count("WHITE")

IN = "PIR-ABC" # This is what goes into the python script
OUT = IN.split("-") # Splits the input into an array
print(OUT) # OUTPUT: ['PIR', '123']

ID = ZONEDevices.index( min(ZONEDevices) ) # OUTPUT HERE IS 2, ZONE-BLUE
if (ID == 0): print("ZONE-RED")
if (ID == 1): print("ZONE-GREEN")
if (ID == 2): print("ZONE-BLUE")
if (ID == 3): print("ZONE-YELLOW")
if (ID == 4): print("ZONE-PURPLE")
if (ID == 5): print("ZONE-WHITE")

DEVICES.append(OUT[0]) # adds the input device type to the devices array
MAC.append(OUT[1]) # adds the input device MAC to the MAC array
print(DEVICES,MAC) # OUTPUT: ['PIR', 'PIR', 'SMOKE', 'PIR'] ['123', '456', '789', 'ABC']

#but what I am wanting to achieve is to get the script to give me the next
#available zone to use if a device is not already active in that zone

#DEVICEZONE.append( UNKNOWN )
```

I hope this makes sense. I am not too sure where to start. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
What you're asking is suited for a tutorial site or general help forum.

Comment: [I’m stuck](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/), without specifics, and without your applicable research, is an issue for a tutor in problem analysis or specification.  It’s not focused enough for Stack Overflow.  Note that you *do* know what logical steps to take next.  You need to work out how you (a human) would do this on paper, and then translate your data representation and process steps into Python.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I have updated my code with a simple example of what i've got so far (I was trying not to over complicate it). Hopefully this explains things abit better... @Prune

Comment: In building question titles, try to aim for the kind of thing you'd see on questions in a FAQ. "Please help" does not fit the format -- the goal is to be as informative as possible in as little space as possible, to help people identify whether they have the information to answer the question, or if they have the same problem and would benefit from its answers.

Comment: Can you refocus this, to be focused less on the larger problem you're trying to solve, and more on the specific technical issue that stymied your attempts at solving it yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem as you have stated it is easy, which makes me think I'm missing something.  This code will tell you the next color for this device type.  A prudent coder would probably add `% len(ZONE)` to avoid overflow:

```
ZONE = ["RED", "GREEN", "BLUE", "YELLOW", "PINK", "WHITE"]
DEVICES = ["PIR", "PIR", "SMOKE"]
MAC = ["123", "456", "789"]
DEVICEZONE = ["RED", "GREEN", "RED"]

def findNextColor( device ):
    k = DEVICES.count(device) % len(ZONE)
    return ZONE[k]

print( "Next PIR is", findNextColor('PIR') )
print( "Next SMOKE is", findNextColor('SMOKE') )
```

Output:

```
Next PIR is BLUE
Next SMOKE is GREEN
```

**FOLLOWUP**

OK, so the specification is not "assign the colors in order".  It's "assign the color with the fewest hits so far, and use the list order if there is a tie."  Note that I build a database that counts the number of occurrences for each device.  I would probably put all of this in a class, which could update the database every time something is added.

Like this:

```
ZONE = ["RED", "GREEN", "BLUE", "YELLOW", "PINK", "WHITE"]
DEVICES = ["PIR", "PIR", "PIR", "PIR","PIR","SMOKE"]
MAC = ["123", "456", "789"]
DEVICEZONE = ["RED", "GREEN", "BLUE", "YELLOW", "PINK","GREEN"]

def distribute( devs, devzones ):
    z1 = { z:0 for z in ZONE }
    tracker = {}
    for d,z in zip(devs,devzones):
        if d not in tracker:
            tracker[d] = z1.copy()
        tracker[d][z] += 1
    return tracker

DB = distribute( DEVICES, DEVICEZONE )
print(DB)

def findNextColor( device ):
    low = min( DB[device].values() )
    return [k for k,v in DB[device].items() if v == low][0]

print( "Next PIR is", findNextColor('PIR') )
print( "Next SMOKE is", findNextColor('SMOKE') )
```

Output:

```
Next PIR is WHITE
Next SMOKE is RED
```

Comment: Thank-you Tim for your answer. This partly works but when the array get more full, and all the zone colours has been used, it needs to then return the next least used colour:

With the example below id expect the next SMOKE colour to be RED as it has not already been used.
When I add another module into that DEVICES array the code crashes but it needs to keep going. If I add another PIR into that array, it needs to then return WHITE as the next available colour followed by RED if another PIR was added. Hope this makes sense :)

Comment: ZONE = ["RED", "GREEN", "BLUE", "YELLOW", "PINK", "WHITE"]
DEVICES = ["PIR", "PIR", "PIR", "PIR","PIR","SMOKE"]
MAC = ["123", "456", "789"]
DEVICEZONE = ["RED", "GREEN", "BLUE", "YELLOW", "PINK","GREEN"]

def findNextColor( device ):
    k = DEVICES.count(device) 
    return ZONE[k]

print( "Next PIR is", findNextColor('PIR') )
print( "Next SMOKE is", findNextColor('SMOKE') )

Comment: Why is the first "SMOKE" assigned to "GREEN"?  That doesn't follow your pattern.  The first device needs to be RED.  I added the "%" up above, as I hinted in my original answer, which lets it wrap around after a device has 6 entries.

Comment: Thanks again Tim, yes that seems to partly work. I can't say ive used the % before in a code like that so not too sure how that works (will look into it more). The reason why smoke was green is because with the modules, I can actually set the zones manually on the deivce which updates the array, hense testing what would happen if the first device [SMOKE] type was GREEN. There may also be cases where there might be more than 1 PIR in one zone to start with like RED RED RED so then the auto assign would assign it to GREEN been the next rather than it just thinking it would be YELLOW next

Comment: Thank you so much, that is exactly what I was looking for!! :)